# SQL Server replication datatype change from tinyint to int

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am trying to change the datatype of one of the columns of a table which is there in the publisher by using the alter command.

And trying to see the changes done at the subscriber end of the table after running the agent. However I'm unable to see the changes.

Please guide.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 is the DBMS being currently referred to here

Comment: Do you see any error after running the agent?

Comment: The schema changes are not being replicated after running the job.However if I try adding a row to it,showing up an error for the schema